Do you agree with ChatGPT’s answer to question: Is vedana a Sankhara?
I asked ChatGPT, Is vedana a sanskhara?
Following is its answer:

In Buddhist philosophy, "vedanā" (feeling or sensation) is distinct
from "saṅkhāra" (mental formations or volitional activities), though
they are both components of the Five Aggregates (pañca-khandha) which
constitute a being.
The Five Aggregates are:

Rūpa: Form or physical body.
Vedanā: Feeling or sensation (pleasant, unpleasant, or neutral experiences).
Saññā: Perception or recognition.
Saṅkhāra: Mental formations or volitional formations (includes all types of mental activities such as intentions, thoughts, desires,
and emotions).
Viññāṇa: Consciousness.

So, vedanā is not the same as saṅkhāra. Vedanā refers specifically to
the experiences of pleasure, pain, or neutrality, whereas saṅkhāra
encompasses a broader range of mental activities and processes,
including the volitional acts that condition future experiences and
actions.

Do you agree with the answer?

@DhammaDhatu Are you saying vedana is not a Sankhara ?

Maybe see the answers to this topic: Can anyone explain Sanskara / Sankara in depth? I think it has a broad meaning, "anything put together" or "every conditioned thing", i.e. perhaps virtually everything except nibbana, and to that extent vedana is a sankhara i.e. it's conditioned -- it also has a ("standard") narrow meaning, identifying a type of mental formation, different from vedana, and in that context "vedana" and "sankhara" are distinct.

AI doesn't understand; AI confabulates. That's not a problem, exactly… everyone who doesn't understand confabulates until they do.  But there's no reason to believe AI can understand. If the wind drops the dharma at your feet, thank the buddha, not the wind.

Re-reading the question, the ChatGPT is obviously incorrect.
The ChatGPT has explained the Five Aggregates correctly but has not answered the question correctly.
The word 'sankhara' has many meanings (refer to this answer). For example, it can mean:

a mental formation produced from sankhara khandha, per SN 22.79:


And why do you call them 'fabrications' (saṅkhāre)? Because they fabricate (saṅkharontī) fabricated things (saṅkhata), thus they are called 'fabrications.' What do they fabricate as a fabricated thing? For the sake of form-ness, they fabricate form as a fabricated thing. For the sake of feeling-ness, they fabricate feeling as a fabricated thing. For the sake of perception-hood... For the sake of fabrication-hood... For the sake of consciousness-hood, they fabricate consciousness as a fabricated thing. Because they fabricate fabricated things, they are called fabrications.
SN 22.79


a 'conditioned phenomena' in general, per SN 22.90:


When this was said, the elder bhikkhus said to the Venerable Channa:
“Form, friend Channa, is impermanent, feeling (vedanā) is impermanent,
perception is impermanent, volitional formations are impermanent,
consciousness is impermanent. Form is nonself, feeling is nonself,
perception is nonself, volitional formations are nonself,
consciousness is nonself. All formations (saṅkhārā) are impermanent; all
phenomena are nonself.
SN 22.90


a requisite condition, namely, 'fabricator' of body, speech & mind:


In-&-out breaths are bodily; these are bound with the body. That's why
in-&-out breaths are the bodily fabricator (kāyasaṅkhāro). Having first directed one's
thoughts and made an evaluation, one then breaks out into speech.
That's why directed thought & evaluation are the verbal fabricator (vacīsaṅkhāro).
Perceptions & feelings are mental; these are bound with the mind.
That's why perceptions & feelings are the mind's fabricator (cittasaṅkhāro).
SN 41.6

Therefore, vedana (feelings) are sankhara types #2 and #3 above; but not sankhara type #1.

Vedanā is described as a cittasankhāra - one of the three types of saṅkhāra - in MN 44. So no I don't agree with its answer. Regardless of the accuracy of the information it gives about the aggregates, it answers your question incorrectly.

I downvoted this answer. In MN 44, vedana is the cittasankhāro. The Pali cittasankhāro is singular. There is only one cittasankharo. This answer gives the impression of saying: "Vedanā is described as one of many cittasaṅkhārā (plural)". "saṅkhārā" = plural. "saṅkhāro" = singular. MN 44 refers to tayome saṅkhārā (three saṅkhārā; plural), which are "kāyasaṅkhāro, vacīsaṅkhāro, cittasaṅkhāro” (each singular). Thanissaro's translation is plainly wrong, which says:: "These three fabrications, friend Visakha: bodily fabrications, verbal fabrications, & mental fabrications."

@DhammaDhatu Perhaps you want to drop the first indefinite article ("a"), to see instead, "Vedanā is described as cittasankhāra - one of the three types of saṅkhāra". Would that address your concern?

Thanks Chris but no. Sāvakohamasmi is obviously a devotee of Thanissaro and it appears both are expressing a wrong view that vedana is something "mental". This view is obvious in Thanissaro's translation.


There are two factors to cittasankhāra - perception and feeling - hence the need for an indefinite article here: "Perceptions & feelings are mental fabrications.” Plural/singular case can be used in Pali compounds in a way unfamiliar to us in English. Pattacīvaraṁ, for example, refers to several things - bowl and robes (outer & upper robe) - yet is frequently given in the singular. It can also be put in the plural as pattacīvarāni. Similarly, cittasankhāra also appears in the plural in MN 44.  So this can be seen as an invalid concern on both counts.



Sister Dhammadinnā - the foremost nun in teaching Dhamma and an arahant - further confirms that "Perceptions & feelings are mental; these are things tied up with the mind. That’s why perceptions & feelings are mental fabrications.” The Buddha confirms at the end of the sutta that she's spoken correctly. Thus the idea that feelings are not mental can in fact be seen to be the real wrong view here.

